# Amount is not displaying in paypal form

Tags: forms, paypal

I am using the following paypal code but still the amount is not displayed in paypal form once the website redirect the page to paypal.

```
 `<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXX">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="200">
<input type="image" style="width: 70px !important; padding: 0px !important;"     src="http://www.merlioncricket.com/Login/static/images/payment.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>`
```

Please let me know, why the amount is not displaying.

Thanks,
Gladiator

Comment: `_s-xclick` is for transferring the total amount of a transaction – so it demands only one `amount` value, without an added number suffix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the answer, & maybe it is useful to others, whenever you create the paypal button make sure in step 2 "Save Button At PayPal" is not clicked & second once you create the button, remove code protection & then select the code & copy the paypal generated code.

It will solve the problem.

Thanks....

Comment: glad to know to you resolved that, do you know as per the current setting of paytm, I am also persisting same issue with paytm.

Answer (score 1):

When using a hosted button, you can not pass over an amount.  The hosted buttons, prevents someone from directly modifying the code and passing over a different amount.  If you are wanting a different amount, you would need to log into your account and edit the hosted button.  If you want to dynamically populate the amount, then you would need to create a non hosted clear text button.

Comment: As you suggested I created the, non hosted clear text button i.e. I choose the option "Save Button At PayPal" in Step 2 so that the button  will not store at paypal server but still the amount field is not populating. I add the "amount" hidden variable in a form but still not working